# Navbar logout button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have created a nav bar, but I can't move the logout button, I want to move it to the right of the screen. I am using bootstrap to build the navbar.

Here is the code I have used so far. How could I move it to the right?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
       <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logout</a>-->

                <?php    //echo $_SESSION["staffname"];
            if(isset($_SESSION["staffId"]) && $_SESSION["staffId"] != NULL)//$_SESSION
            {        ?> <a class="navbar-brand">
                     Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["staffname"];  ?></a>
               <a href="logout.php" class="navbar-brand"><strong>Logout</strong></a>
             <?php
             }
             ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: I think that [tag:bootstrap] is wrong (see its description), but not sure what to replace it with - [tag:twitter-bootstrap]? [tag:angular-ui-bootstrap]? something else?  Please edit; thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pull it to the right and remove navbar-brand: `class="pull-right"`.
Because `navbar-brand` is `float-left` styled.

Bootstrap style is as it:

```
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Your code should be:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <!--<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Logout</a>-->

            <?php    //echo $_SESSION["staffname"];
        if(isset($_SESSION["staffId"]) && $_SESSION["staffId"] != NULL)//$_SESSION
        {        ?> <a href="logout.php" class="pull-right">    <strong>Logout</strong></a>
<a class="pull-left">Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION["staffname"];  ?></a>

         <?php
         }
         ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it there now, but it moves the logout to the left.

Comment: Remove navbar-brand. It's used only for Brand tag, not other buttons.

Comment: which part do I remove?

Comment: the css bootstrap class `navbar-brand` is float-left, so you have to remove navbar-brand class AND add pull-right class in order to put your content to the right.

Comment: Thank you,I tried using the code, but I still have the same dilemma, the login moves to the left of the 'welcome'.

Comment: Oh ok, juste exchange position of both welcome and login. (because float invert natural order). So : `<a ...>logout</a> then <a ...>welcome</a>`

Comment: thank you! Perhaps I have not made it clear, I need the logout button to be on the opposite side of the welcome, as in the top right corner and welcome in the top left. When I make the changes you suggested it swaps the welcome with the logout, but the button does not move where I need it to go.

Comment: Just use `pull-right` class when you want anything to the right and `pull-left` when you want anything to the left :)